# Trouble with C++ Class

Tags: c++, vector

I am a teacher at an independent boarding school and am trying to to write a program in C++ that will randomly seat students at tables in our dining hall so that they sit with different students and with different staff members each week.  Ideally, over a given period, they would not sit at the same table twice and with as many different students as possible.  I have created this program in Python and it works great (well, pretty good).  For a variety of reasons, I am trying to port this over to C++ (which I do not know well at all) so I can hand it off to the boarding staff.  Both student and staff (as well as table capacities) are read from text files.  I have created two custom classes, one for students and one for tables, to handle the data.  Here are the two class header files:

Table.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "Student.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Table
{
    // Private class variables
    string staff;
    int numSeats;
    vector<Student> seating;
public:
    Table(); // Default constructor
    Table(string s, int n);
    Table(const Table& that) : staff(that.staff), numSeats(that.numSeats)
    {
    }
    // Copy Constructor
    Table& operator=(const Table& that)
    {
        staff = that.staff;
        numSeats = that.numSeats;
        return *this;
    }
    int getNumSeats();
    string getStaffName();
    void addStudent(Student student);
    void removeStudent(Student student);
    void clearStudents();
    vector<Student> getTableSeating();
    int getRemainingSeats();
    ~Table(void);
};
```

Here is the student class file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
    string name;
    string country;
    vector<int> tablesSatAt;
public:
    Student(string n, string c);
    Student();
    Student(const Student& that) : name(that.name), country(that.country)
    {
    }
    Student& operator=(const Student& that)
    {
        name = that.name;
        country = that.country;
        return *this;
    }
    string getName();
    string getCountry();
    void addTable(int tableNumber);
    void removeTable(int tableNumber);
    bool satAtTable(int tableNumber);
    friend bool operator==(Student s1, Student s2);
    friend bool operator!=(Student s1, Student s2);
    ~Student(void);
};

bool operator==(Student s1, Student s2);
bool operator!=(Student s1, Student s2);
```

Here is the recursion function that does the heavy lifting:

```
bool seatRecursive(vector<Student> &tempStudents, vector<Table> &tempTables)
{
    if (tempStudents.size() == 0) return true; //base case

    Student nextStudent = randomSelect(tempStudents);
    for (vector<int>::size_type i=0; i<tempTables.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tempTables[i].getRemainingSeats() > 0 && !nextStudent.satAtTable(i))
        {
            addStudentToTable(nextStudent, tempTables, i);
            if (seatRecursive(tempStudents, tempTables)) return true;
            else 
            {
                removeStudentFromTable(nextStudent, tempTables, i);
                tempStudents.push_back(nextStudent);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Most of this works.  When I run the program, I get a text file with 10 weeks of seating, but all the table seatings are the same.  i.e. if I am a particular staff member, I have the same kids sitting at my table for all 10 weeks.  I have a vector of ints that is supposed to be storing the table numbers that a student has sat at over time.  When debugging, I notice that those table numbers are NOT being stored in that vector, it is always empty.  My problem is that I can't figure out why this is happening.  Is it because I am passing the vectors by reference?  Does it have something to do with pointers, even though I am not explicitly declaring pointers?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and I can paste in the rest of the code if necessary.

Brian

Comment: holy wall of text, what's your question?

Comment: what code calls seatRecursive? what's inside addStudentToTable?

Comment: @wich, he wants to know why a student's "table history" is not being stored. His debugging shows that his vector `vector<int> tablesSatAt` is not being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that both copy constructors (and assignment constructors) of `Student` and `Table` class forget about copying the STL vectors contained (`vector<Student> seating` and `vector<int> tablesSatAt`). Since you overload those constructors you should copy them through `vector` copy constructor as it is not implicitly done.

Without copying them, every time a `Student` or a `Table` is moved around a vector (or assigned to a temporary) the internal vector is just discarded for the new object.

As pointed out by Useless's comment in this case you don't need to declare them since the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) doesn't apply: you don't need a destructor so probably you won't need the two copy constructors.

A note: what you call copy constructor in your comment is the copy assignment constructor instead. The one before is the real copy constructor.

Comment: Or just don't write the copy constructor at all. The compiler-generated one will do this fine.

Comment: The odd thing is that IIRC, until I wrote those two constructors, the code would not even compile.  Of course, it may completely be the way I was doing things.  I will try both suggestions of removing the copy constructor and copying the STL vectors.  Thanks.

Comment: @Useless: You were right about the copy constructor, when I commented those functions out, the program still compiled correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I did not need the copy constructors, etc. as outlined here.  I did, however, need to pass the vector of students as a reference in all places, which I was not doing.

Answer (score 6):

Why make it difficult?

Just put all your students in a vector, then use the STL random_shuffle algorithm, and finally just put the resulting vector of students linearly at all your available tables.

You don't even need custom classes for students or tables really

Comment: I still need a way to keep track of where students have sat so they do not repeat tables.  Also, since each table has a different amount of available seats, I need a way to keep track of that as well as well as the staff member assigned to a particular table.